# How to inflate a layout in GridView adapter

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I have populated a `GridView` with some `grid_items`.

**I am looking for a way to inflate a new layout (let's call it `pop_up_layout.xml`) that would occupy only a portion of the screen and this event should be triggered when clicking a button placed in a certain `grid_item` view.** I know I have to place the functionality in the adapter at the current item's position.

My purpose is to display more info about the `grid_item` as well as providing new options for the users through new buttons in the `pop_up_layout.xml` that is being inflated.

I have searched and skimmed through most of the questions related in SO as well as websites but I seem to find solutions only to display pop-up views.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Something like [this](https://lh5.ggpht.com/lmhbpOGsgrcbM9YBlAXshpzXbAkiTGDv4_XmD9pK_OaILYRbXuWVVE37z5SWf2f50BbU=h900) is what I am looking for.

Comment: You could use dialogfragment for that and you can send data from the grid view to the Fragment so that it can show the relative content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DialogFragment for your case inflating layout is not the perfect answer.

To open the fragment you can use in the on click of your grid item

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        BaseDialogFragment Fragment = new BaseDialogFragment();
        transaction.add(fragment, "loading");
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("your_data", yourdata);
// you can add as many string int or boolean. Explore it.
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();





     public class BaseDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

            Typeface MR, MRR;

            @Override
            public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
                getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);



            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {

                super.onStart();

                Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
                WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = window.getAttributes();
                windowParams.dimAmount = 0.50f;

                window.setAttributes(windowParams);
            }

            public void onResume() {

                super.onResume();
                WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
                params.width = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                params.height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(params);



            }

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container, false);

                // init your views here. or 
get the data here from the Grid View
                String your_data = getArguments().getString("your_data");

                return v;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your answer is spot-on, it has everything I need, nice explanations. I will  implement it shortly and test it. Regarding the actual code, I do have some questions as I don't like to write code I don't fully comprehend. If you have the time I can leave them in comments. Regarding the downvote I received, I would really like to see an explanation from the person that actually gave it. At least I can filter my words better and improve my questions in the future.